# Passing variables from PHP to C++

Tags: c++, php, junior-programmer

I need to call a program from PHP and pass some vars and/or sets of key-value pairs to it. How do I pass these vars, through arguments to the called function?

`exec("/path/to/program flag1 flag2 [key1=A,key2=B]");`

Or is there a better method to achieve this? Somebody suggested to me to write them into a txt file and pass the path to it to as an argument instead,

`exec("/path/to/program path_to_txt_file);`

but I’m not to excited about this method.

Comment: could probably just pass in a single serialized argument (like querystring style) and parse it in your c++ application...

Comment: Is that for Unix like? When you pass arguments in the commandline, they are visible to others who do `ps ax`. Another possibility could be that you write strings terminated with \n to the program's fd 0 or to a fifo.

Comment: @ott-- Yes, Linux environment.

Comment: Is it just me, or should this be on StackOverflow?

Comment: And FWIW, if you have a lot of data to pass you should write it to the child process' [STDIN](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stdin/). The most flexible way to do this from PHP is with [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc-open). If you need to pass complex data (e.g. some vector type) you should use a standard serialisation mechanism such as JSON.

Comment: I'd try to wrap the C source (if you can recompile it) as a PHP extension: http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/

Comment: @DaveRandom - I don't think so. It's a design rather than implementation problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways that come to mind: doing Inter-Process Communication, building a C++ PHP extension/dll, or directly using the CLI.

You can have your PHP scripts take in shell parameters as you are suggesting (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763997/shell-run-execute-php-script-with-parameters). You can evolve this to passing a single argument in the form of a query string, taking $argv[0] and set it to $_GET or $_POST, or whatever you prefer. Test it with something like:

```
<?php

parse_str($argv[0], $_POST);
```

Finally, for a more "correct" solution (using socket based communication), you might want to take a look at [**Thrift**](http://thrift.apache.org/). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746207/how-to-ipc-between-php-clients-and-a-c-daemon-server

Comment: I’m trying to execute the C++ program called from PHP, not the other way around (as in your first link example). The C++ needs take the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo out the variables in php and read the returned data from the HTTP request . After sending your request, you can probably use **InternetQueryDataAvailable** to get the number of bytes coming back, allocate a buffer large enough to accommodate the data, and use **InternetReadFile** to get the data into the buffer.